# Minha lista duplamente encadeada não esta ordenando

Tags: java, lista

Classe No Duplo

```
package ListaDuplamenteEncadeada;

public class NoDuplo {
    private Integer elemento;
    private NoDuplo anterior;
    private NoDuplo proximo;


    public NoDuplo(Integer elemento, NoDuplo anterior, NoDuplo proximo) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
        this.anterior= anterior;
        this.proximo = proximo;

    }

    public Integer getElemento() {
        return elemento;
    }
    public void setElemento(Integer elemento) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }
    public NoDuplo getAnterior(){
        return anterior;
    }
    public void setAnterior(NoDuplo anterior){
        this.anterior = anterior;
    }
    public NoDuplo getProximo() {
        return proximo;
    }
    public void setProximo(NoDuplo proximo) {
        this.proximo = proximo;
    }   
}
```

Classe ListaDuplamenteEncadeada

```
package ListaDuplamenteEncadeada;

public class ListaDuplamenteEncadeada {
    private Integer tamanho;
    private NoDuplo header;
    private NoDuplo trailer;

    public ListaDuplamenteEncadeada() {
        tamanho = 0;
        header = new NoDuplo(null, null, null);
        trailer = new NoDuplo(null, null, null);
        header.setProximo(trailer);
        trailer.setAnterior(header);
    }

    public int getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public NoDuplo getPrimeiro() {
        if (tamanho == 0) {
            System.out.println("lista vazia");
            return null;
        }
        return header.getProximo();
    }

    public NoDuplo getUltimo() {
        if (tamanho == 0) {
            System.out.println("lista vazia");
            return null;
        }
        return trailer.getAnterior();
    }

    public void insereInicio(NoDuplo novoNo) {

        novoNo.setAnterior(header);
        novoNo.setProximo(header.getProximo());

        header.getProximo().setAnterior(novoNo);
        header.setProximo(novoNo);

        tamanho++;
        return;
    }

    public void insereFinal(NoDuplo novoNo) {
        novoNo.setAnterior(trailer.getAnterior());
        novoNo.setProximo(trailer);
        trailer.getAnterior().setProximo(novoNo);
        trailer.setAnterior(novoNo);

        tamanho++;
        return;
    }

    public void inserePos(NoDuplo novoNo, int pos) {
        if (pos < 1 || pos > tamanho + 1) {
            System.out.println("posi��o inv�lida");
            return;
        }
        if (tamanho == 0 || pos == 0) {
            insereInicio(novoNo);
            return;
        }
        if (pos == tamanho + 1) {
            insereFinal(novoNo);
            return;
        }

        NoDuplo aux = header.getProximo();
        for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
            aux = aux.getProximo();
        }
        // novoNo REFERENCIA SEU PROXIMO E SEU ANTERIOR
        novoNo.setProximo(aux);
        novoNo.setAnterior(aux.getAnterior());

        // novoNo � REFERENCIADO PELO SEU ANTERIOR E PELO SEU PROXIMO
        aux.getAnterior().setProximo(novoNo);
        aux.setAnterior(novoNo);

        tamanho++;
    }

    public void removeInicio() {
        if (tamanho == 0) {
            System.out.println("lista vazia");
            return;
        }
        NoDuplo noRemovido = header.getProximo();
        header.setProximo(noRemovido.getProximo());
        header.getProximo().setAnterior(header);

        noRemovido.setAnterior(null);
        noRemovido.setProximo(null);

        tamanho--;
        return;
    }

    public void removeFim() {
        if (tamanho == 0) {
            System.out.println("lista vazia");
            return;
        }
        NoDuplo noRemovido = trailer.getAnterior();
        trailer.setAnterior(noRemovido.getAnterior());
        trailer.getAnterior().setProximo(trailer);

        noRemovido.setAnterior(null);
        noRemovido.setProximo(null);

        tamanho--;
    }

    public void removePos(int pos) {
        if (pos < 1 || pos > tamanho) {
            System.out.println("posi��o inv�lida");
            return;
        }

        if (pos == 1) {
            removeInicio();
            return;
        }

        if (pos == tamanho) {
            removeFim();
            return;
        }

        NoDuplo noRemovido = header.getProximo();
        for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
            noRemovido = noRemovido.getProximo();

        noRemovido.getAnterior().setProximo(noRemovido.getProximo());
        noRemovido.getProximo().setAnterior(noRemovido.getAnterior());

        noRemovido.setAnterior(null);
        noRemovido.setProximo(null);
        tamanho--;
    }

    public void ordenarLista() {
        NoDuplo atual = header.getProximo();
        NoDuplo prox = atual.getProximo();

        System.out.println("Atual antes do for " + atual.getElemento());
        System.out.println("Prox Antes do for " + prox.getElemento());

        NoDuplo cpAtual = atual;
        System.out.println("Cpatual antes do For " + cpAtual.getElemento());

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < tamanho; j++) {
                if (atual.getElemento() > prox.getElemento()) {
                    cpAtual.setElemento(atual.getElemento());
                    System.out.println("Cp atual dentro do FOR j + if " + cpAtual.getElemento());
                    atual.setElemento(prox.getElemento());
                    System.out.println("Atual dentro do FOR J + if " + atual.getElemento());
                    prox.setElemento(cpAtual.getElemento());
                    System.out.println("Prox Dentro do FOR J + if " + prox.getElemento());
                }
                prox = prox.getProximo();
                System.out.println("Prox DENTRO DO FOR J sem IF " + prox.getElemento());
            }
            atual = atual.getProximo();
            System.out.println("Atual dentro do FOR I " + atual.getElemento());
            prox = atual.getProximo();
            System.out.println("Prox dentro do FOR I " + prox.getElemento());
            cpAtual = atual;
            System.out.println("Cpatual dentro do FOR I " + cpAtual.getElemento());

        }

    }

    public void imprimeLista() {
        if (tamanho == 0) {
            System.out.println("lista vazia");
        }
        NoDuplo aux = header.getProximo();
        System.out.println("------------- LISTA ATUAL -----------");
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            System.out.print(" -> " + aux.getElemento() + "\t");
            aux = aux.getProximo();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Ele não ta ordenando ele, não ta mudando a referencia do menor valor.

Comment: Está utilizando o bubble sort para ordenar?

Comment: Tentando usar a mesma logica do método bolha, mas o negocio é que o valor prox, por exemplo o vetor[i+i] não esta atualizando o valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que faz a ordenação não funcionar é a troca (*swap*) de valores dentro do segundo `for` que não está correta. Não nos podemos esquecer que uma troca de valores entre duas variáveis envolve sempre uma terceira variável temporária.

Algo como:

```
int x = ...;
int y = ...;

//troca 
int temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

Que não é o que está feito aqui (cortando os `System.out` para ficar curto):

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < tamanho; j++) {
    if (atual.getElemento() > prox.getElemento()) {
        cpAtual.setElemento(atual.getElemento());                 
        atual.setElemento(prox.getElemento());  
        prox.setElemento(cpAtual.getElemento());                    
    }
    ...
}
```

Em que `atual` e `cpAtual` são na verdade o mesmo nó:

```
...
System.out.println("Prox dentro do FOR I " + prox.getElemento());
cpAtual = atual;
...
```

Logo trocar um também troca outro. Para além disso o próprio `cpAtual` não é necessário para o método de ordenação podendo ser feito apenas com o `atual` e o `proximo`, assim:

```
public void ordenarLista() {
    NoDuplo atual = header.getProximo();
    NoDuplo prox = atual.getProximo();

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < tamanho; j++) {
            if (atual.getElemento() > prox.getElemento()) {
                //a troca de variaveis agora de forma correta
                Integer temp = atual.getElemento(); //temp = x
                atual.setElemento(prox.getElemento()); // x = y
                prox.setElemento(temp); // y = temp
            }

            prox = prox.getProximo();
        }

        atual = atual.getProximo();
        prox = atual.getProximo();
   }

}
```

Cortei também os `System.out` por legibilidade.

**Duas notas adicionais importantes:**

1. O nó `header` e `trailer` já são nós e por isso tem valores, também tem um `elemento`, no entanto estes nunca são utilizados! Porque qualquer navegação na lista começa no próximo do header:

   ```
   public NoDuplo getPrimeiro() {
       if (tamanho == 0) {
          ...
       }
       return header.getProximo();
   }
   ```

   Ou no anterior do trailer:

   ```
   public NoDuplo getUltimo() {
       if (tamanho == 0) {
          ...
       }
       return trailer.getAnterior();
   }
   ```

   O que significa que existem sempre dois nós vazios na lista.
2. Os conceitos de encapsulamento não estão corretamente aplicados, pois não é possível inserir um elemento na lista sem utilizar a classe `NoDuplo`:

   ```
   public void insereInicio(NoDuplo novoNo)
   public void insereFinal(NoDuplo novoNo)
   public void inserePos(NoDuplo novoNo, int pos)
   ```

   Isto força a que o código que utiliza a lista dependa diretamente da classe `NoDuplo` e consequentemente da sua implementação. Passando a não ser possível por exemplo trocar a implementação para um `NoSimples` sem trocar o código que utiliza a lista.

   Em vez disso a classe deveria receber apenas os elementos e criar os nós dentro dos métodos de adição, desta forma:

   ```
   public void insereFinal(Integer novoElemento) {
       NoDuplo novoNo = new NoDuplo(novoElemento, null, null);
       ...
   }
   ```

   E para complementar um construtor de `NoDuplo` que metesse as duas referências a `null` também ajudava bastante para ser ainda mais simples e se poder fazer:

   ```
   NoDuplo novoNo = new NoDuplo(novoElemento);
   ```

Comment: Muito obrigado <3